# Can you have two of the same regex but point to them to different url files

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, url

For example is the following allowed? If so, is it not recommended or is it okay?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('login.urls')),
    url(r'^$' include('register.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set it up in django, but the second one will not be used, because django will find the url from top to bottom, when it found the match record, django will return the first record and stop there, so, the second one could not have chance to execute.

Answer (score 0):

No, Django will math the first regex.

But you can for example set one regex for one view
and than in that view do specific operations based on the type of the request (GET/POST/PUT etc)

```
class CommentView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        ... do if get type    

    def post(self, request):
        ... do if post type
```

And also you can check in view if user is logged in or not, if not you can redirect them to login.